# Can't open port 80 externally with Windows XP Professional SP3

Tags: windows-xp, windows-firewall

I have Windows XP Professional, SP3. I'm running a webserver which listens on port 80. I have a dedicated ip address. Localhost on 80 resolves ok:

```
http://localhost:80
```

but I cannot get it to resolve externally:

```
http://external.ip.address:80
```

I can however get another port to resolve externally:

```
http://external.ip.address:1234
```

The Windows personal firewall is turned off. I've also stopped IIS. Is there something else that could prevent this from working?

Comment: Your router, possibly.

Comment: Hmm no router, cable line goes direct to the machine.

Comment: You still have a router, whether it's called a "cable modem" or router, its job is to route traffic to your computer.

Comment: Please clarify - what web server software are you using?

Comment: @mark Please run this command and post the output.  It will tell us if the web server is listening on the external IP or not: `netstat -an | find ":80" | find "LISTENING"`

Comment: Running the command prints: "TCP 0.0.0.0:80  0.0.0.0:0   LISTERNING"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you have restarted IIS/turned it back on.

This will be down to one of two things:

1) You have not set up your router correctly. Whilst some applications such as games can use UPnP or other technologies to "bypass" / create rules on the router, many server based applications are designed for corporate environments which do not allow this. You will need to forward the ports yourself. Take a look at [Port Forward](http://portforward.com/) for information on how to do this if you are not sure.

2) Your ISP blocks it. This is unlikely if you have been issued a static IP, however it is possible - a lot of ISPs block port 25 and 80. If this is the case, you can ask them to unblock it, however no guarantees that they will. It depends on their policy.

Comment: No router. It's probably the isp. Resolves just fine from the outside if I use a port other than 80. Resolves internally if port 80. I'm sure iis is not running.

Comment: @mark - IIS (or whatever webserver you are using) NEEDS to be running! - IIS is what responds to port 80, you would not be able to access the website from other machines on your network if port 80 was off.

Comment: ... However, you may also want to check the bindings of the website in IIS are set to all and not just your internal IP.

Comment: Check with your ISP - some ISPs may permit you to enable port 80 access but have it disabled by default (mine, for business, does this).

Comment: Mark is __not__ using IIS but a third party webserver - hence __IIS is turned off__ *and* __I can get to port 80 internally__.

Comment: @Matt Jenkins - That is why I said "or whatever webserver you are using"... It wasn't very clear as it started by saying he had access and ended via "i've also stopped IIS"

Comment: Sorry, but the way you were commenting you were saying to try things in IIS

Comment: @Matt Kenkins in one comment it was in case that is what he was using... it still isn't 100% clear.

Comment: @Wil Clarification from the querrant requested.

Comment: Right I have Jetty running. Again, can resolve localhost:80 locally ok, it's just from the outside that's the problem. I'll talk to my isp today, I'm guessing they blocked 80 from the outside.

Comment: Yeah the ISP was blocking it even though it's a static IP business account. They opened it now.